# How to use NSCursor to display custom cursor

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscursor

I am trying to use custom cursor in my game using nscursor.  I use following code

```
//While initializing openglview 
    mCustomCursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:image hotSpot:NSZeroPoint];
    [image release];
[mCustomCursor set]
```

I am setting cursor rect in resetcursorrect method

```
- (void)resetCursorRects
{

    [self  addCursorRect:currentViewPortRect cursor:[NSCursor currentCursor]];

}
```

Custom cursor appears, It is not consistent, at times it switches back to system cursor (for alerts), some times it comes back and sometime not. It is  so confusing. I am not sure if I should use 'setOnMouseEntered', 'pop'. What is the standard way to use nscursor and change it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the cursor to the current cursor, which isn't changing it at all. To display your own custom cursor, you must pass your custom cursor when creating the cursor rect.

Comment: Agreed, But when should I use [NSCursor pop] ,[NSCursor push]? If I used [NSCursor push] can I use ` [self  addCursorRect:currentViewPortRect cursor:[NSCursor currentCursor]];`

Comment: @shakthi: You generally shouldn't, and the same goes for `-[NSCursor set]`. When using a cursor rect, you don't need to and shouldn't change the cursor manually—that's what the cursor rect is for. Don't pass `currentCursor` to `addCursorRect:cursor:`; the point of adding a cursor rect is to change the cursor when the user passes over it—changing the current cursor to the current cursor makes no sense. Just add the cursor rect with your custom cursor.

Comment: Thanks a LOT. I was struggling for a week to make it straight.

Comment: '@'Peter:How can I change cursor efficiently when user presses mouse button change it back when he releases? Right now I am calling  '[[view window] invalidateCursorRectsForView:view];'. It works fine but is it the right method?

Comment: @shakthi: No; I'm not sure why you want to do that, but assuming you have a good reason, that's actually a case in which to use push and pop.

Comment: Its actually a game. I need to implement drag and drop of some objects. I want to use the openHandCursor before picking, the closeHandCursor while dragging and again  the openHandCursor after dropping.

Comment: @shakthi: Yup, sounds good. Use a cursor rect for the open-hand, and push the closed hand when the drag begins and pop it when it ends.

Comment: Cursor rect method is not working when I have nested cursor rects. Moment  I added nested rect and moved the (mouse) cursor from inner most cursor rect to the outer rect it changes to system cursor. The behavior will correct when I move the cursor out of the screen and then inside.