# OSX Cocoa cursor in resources

Tags: macos, cocoa, resources, cursor

ALL,

On Windows cursors are indicated by the `cur` file extension. Is there something similar for OSX Cocoa application?

Is there a way in XCode to edit such files, just like in MSVC there is some basic graphical editor?

Also, is there a special API which will allow loading such files on Cocoa? Or I can just load them as images?

TIA!!

EDIT:

In the meantime I think I found a good solution that will satisfy my needs

```
NSString *path;
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:cursor_file ofType:@"cur"];
if( path )
{
    CGImageSourceRef image = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( path, nil );
    CFDictionaryRef properties =
```

CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex( image, 0, nil );
NSInteger x = properties["hotspotX"];
NSInteger y = properties["hotspotY"];
}

Except that it doesn't compile:

I need to import the file where CGImageSourceCreateWithURL() is declared, and I need to fix the last 2 lines, because the array subscript can't be strings.

Could someone help, please?

Comment: How about `NSCursor`?

Comment: @Willeke, how do I create one? And is there a way to load fro Resource folder? I didnt find any download API... I want to use custom cursor loaded from resources

Comment: @Willeke, or maybe there is a way to convert Windows cursor to Mac cursor and se it in my application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NSCursor to display custom cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608733/how-to-use-nscursor-to-display-custom-cursor)

Comment: @Willeke, it does, to some extent. I still need to know what type of file I can use - png,  jpg,  svg, cur or maybe osx have some specific cursor type? And how to create one? And if I can oppen one of the predefined cursors in that editor. My cursor is modified hand cursor. So if I can open that icon, I can clone it with my modification.

Comment: @Willeke, can you help me fix compiler errors? I made some edits for OP...

Comment: You can't use subscripts on `CFDictionaryRef`. Bridge `properties` to `NSDictionary` or use a `CFDictionary` function.

Comment: @Willeke, how? And what do I import for the first question?

Comment: See [Casting a CFDictionaryRef to NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018497/casting-a-cfdictionaryref-to-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following source code will create a custom NSCursor in Xcode from a .cur image, after retrieving its “hotspot” coordinates from the file located in the app bundle Resource folder.  Replace the contents of the main.m file with the code below and delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate files to avoid duplicate symbols. You will need to copy/paste the .cur file into the Xcode project folder and also drag and drop it into the Project navigator.  Xcode will **not** automatically place this file into the Resources folder of your application bundle (unlike a .png file), so copy/paste it there as well after you have compiled the app.  Reference: [Hotspot in Windows cursor .cur loaded by NSImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875707/hotspot-in-windows-cursor-cur-loaded-by-nsimage)

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
  NSWindow *window;
  CGFloat x,y;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) customCursor {
    // **** Get HotSpot from .cur file **** //
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *url = [bundle URLForImageResource:@"myCursor.cur"];
    if( url ) {
    CGImageSourceRef image = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( (__bridge CFURLRef)url, nil );
    NSDictionary *properties = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex( image, 0, nil );
        x = [[properties objectForKey:@"hotspotX"]floatValue];
        y = [[properties objectForKey:@"hotspotY"]floatValue];
        CFBridgingRelease(image);
        CFBridgingRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)(properties));
    }
    NSCursor *customCursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"myCursor.cur"] hotSpot: NSMakePoint( x, y) ];
    [customCursor set];
    NSLog(@"x = %0.02f",x);
    NSLog(@"y = %0.02f",y);
    
}

- (void) arrowCursor {
 [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}

- (void) buildMenu {
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
 NSMenuItem *menuBarItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 [menubar addItem:menuBarItem];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 [menuBarItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
 [appMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
}

- (void) buildWnd {

 #define _wndW  500
 #define _wndH  250

 window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )  styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
 [window center];
 [window setTitle: @"Custom cursor"];
 [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// **** Button 1 **** //
 NSButton *myBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 30, 30, 135, 30 )];
 [myBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
 [myBtn setTitle: @"Custom Cursor"];
 [myBtn setAction: @selector (customCursor)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: myBtn];

// **** Button 2 **** //
 NSButton *myBtn2 =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 190, 30, 135, 30 )];
 [myBtn2 setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
 [myBtn2 setTitle: @"Arrow Cursor"];
 [myBtn2 setAction: @selector (arrowCursor)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: myBtn2];

// **** Quit btn **** //
 NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 )];
 [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
 [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
 [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
 [self buildMenu];
 [self buildWnd];
}

@end

int main() {
NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[application setDelegate:appDelegate];
[application run];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for that. Just one question - does this mean that by default OSX have `png` as a cursor file? And there is no special cursor file format/extension?

Comment: There is no special format/extension for a MacOS cursor.  NSCursor is an NSObject which may be initialized with an image of the user's choosing.  The image has no default file type; possibilities include .png, .tiff, .icns and likely others that I have not tested.  You'll have to experiment with other file types if you want something special.

Comment: ok. understood. There is no special format for OSX cursor. So I think I will try to use the cur file I made on Windows.

Comment: I made some edits to the OP. Can you help me fix the errors?

Comment: It might be easier to convert the .cur to a .png; there are online services to do this (I have no experience).

Comment: probably. But I' trying to decrease number of files in my project. And most importantly eliminate duplicates...

Comment: I just added a .cur file to my Xcode project and installed the image on the custom cursor using the code above.  It worked ok; no need to convert to .png.

Comment: did you change the file extension to `cur`? Also - how do you now where the hotspot is for the cursor?

Comment: The file had a .cur extension when I downloaded it.  You'll have to change the name of the file in the demo that I posted.  Hotspot is wherever you set it in the code that I posted.  Xcode does not automatically put the file in your app's bundle Resource folder (like it does with png file) so you have to manually copy/paste it.

Comment: I think my code is better. It gets the hotspot from the image itself and I ca. Use any extension I want. Your hardworking it which means it is not generic.

Comment: Original answer edited to include retrieval of hotspot coordinates from app bundle/Resource .cur file.

Comment: @aptodidae,I accepted your answer with the big thank you.